# How do I run the debugger in Android Studio in order to figure out this error?

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

When my app goes from one screen to the other, there is a very brief moment where the app shows the red screen with some error about a `Null` in yellow letters and then it disappears. Is there a way to run Android Studio in a "step-by-step" way so that I can see exactly what variable is `Null` and when it gets filled?

```
======== Exception caught by widgets library =======================================================
The following _TypeError was thrown building ChatScreen(dirty, dependencies: [_InheritedStateContainer], state: _ChatScreenState#93181):
type 'Null' is not a subtype of type 'String'
```

**Code:**

```
return GestureDetector(
                  child: groupWidget(groupName, groupID),
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => ChatScreen(groupID: groupID,)), //The error is on this line
                    );
                  }
              );
```

**Update:**
Ok so I found a way to start the debugger, set a breakpoint where the error was pointing to, and then stepped through each line using `F7`. It looks like the problem isn't actually on this starting screen, it's on the landing screen (which is strange because the console points to a line on the starting screen). The problem is with the variable `groupName` in the code below. For some reason it starts as `Null` and then gets filled. My intention here is that when the user loads this screen, the name of the group is retrieved from Firestore and then displayed at the top. Why would this variable be null if I'm initializing it in `initState()`?

```
class _ChatScreenState extends State<ChatScreen> {
  final database = Database();
  var groupMembersList = [];
  var groupName;
  FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
  late final Stream<QuerySnapshot> groupMembersStream = firestore.collection('groups').doc(widget.groupID).collection('GroupMembers').snapshots();

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    initialize();
    activateGroupMembersListener();
  }

  void initialize() async {
    var tempGroupName = await database.getGroupName(widget.groupID);

    setState(() {
      groupName = tempGroupName;
    });
  }
  
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final container = StateContainer.of(context);

    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.arrow_back),
          color: Colors.white,
          onPressed: () {
            container.stopMyApp();
            Navigator.pop(context);
          },
        ),
        title: Text(
          groupName, //ERROR IS HERE, THIS VARIABLE IS NULL
        ),
        
        //...rest of code//
        
        )
    )
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding a breakpoint where you initialized groupName should help, also at MaterialPageRoute line.